# Using a word as a delimiter for strtok?

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a file and identify instances of a word provided in the command line.  However when I use this:

```
strtok(line,argv[2])
```

it identifies any instance of any letter present in argv[2] (as I understand this is how strtok works) but I only want it to identify exact matches of the string.  If I'm required to use strtok, is there a way around this? Thanks!

Comment: Why would anyone require you to use `strtok` for this?  It's silly.  It is plainly the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. What you need is `strstr`.

Comment: Couldn't tell you why. I understand that strstr is the clear choice here but strtok and nothing else is the requirement.

Comment: It sounds like you are supposed to use `strtok` to break up the line into words, then manually match each word against your command line entry.  What are you supposed to **do** when you **identify** a word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the function `strstr(char *str1, char *str2)`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
    char str[] ="A random string.";
    char *pch;

    pch = strstr(str,"random");

    if(pch == NULL)
    {
        puts("Doesn't contain random");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("Contains random");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

strtok will tokanize the string based on the given list as the second argument. it will use the combination of characters. for example if second argument contains a string "abcd", then the strtok will token the strings if it founds 'a', 'ab', 'abc' or 'abcd'.
As per your requirement, you can use strstr(string,substring). this function will return you the pointer of the first occurrence of the string. By using this function you can write your own function which will tokenize the string in substrings based on you requrement.